# How to make an IEnumerable of values of tree nodes?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, lazy-evaluation

Consider the following class:

```
class TreeNode
{
    int value;
    public TreeNode l, r;
    public TreeNode(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public IEnumerable<int> sub_values()
    {
        if (l != null)
            foreach (int i in l.sub_values())
                yield return i;
        if (r != null)
            foreach (int i in r.sub_values())
                yield return i;
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

Each value is passed `O(h)` times, where `h` is the height of the tree. First, in `yield return value;` statement, then in `yield return i;` of each parent node.

So, `sub_values` returns `n` values using `O(nh)` time complexity.

I can replace it with a method, which accepts a reference to a list of integers and instead of returning values, adds them to this list, but it won't be lazy anymore.

Can I return `n` values in `O(n)` and maintain laziness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very similar to [Function which will return particular node from tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025236/function-which-will-return-particular-node-from-tree-structure/32053484#32053484) and other SO posts regarding recursive iterators. All they involve using an explicit stack or queue. Here is a generic solution for any type of tree. Let first define a reusable function in some common place, so the next time [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```
public static class TreeHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(T node, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector, bool preOrder = true)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<T>>();
        var e = Enumerable.Repeat(node, 1).GetEnumerator();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    var item = e.Current;
                    var children = childrenSelector(item);
                    if (children == null)
                        yield return item;
                    else
                    {
                        if (preOrder) yield return item;
                        stack.Push(e);
                        e = children.GetEnumerator();
                    }
                }
                if (stack.Count == 0) break;
                e.Dispose();
                e = stack.Pop();
                if (!preOrder) yield return e.Current;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            e.Dispose();
            while (stack.Count != 0) stack.Pop().Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Now let define some useful helpers inside your `TreeNode` class

```
public bool AnyChildren() { return l != null || r != null; }
public IEnumerable<TreeNode> Children
{
    get
    {
        if (l != null) yield return l;
        if (r != null) yield return r;
    }
}
public IEnumerable<TreeNode> Traverse(bool preOrder = false)
{
    return TreeHelper.Traverse(this, node => node.AnyChildren() ? node.Children : null, preOrder);
}
```

Notice the `Traverse` method - it provides the laziness you are asking for. Now you can use the usual LINQ methods for filtering, projections etc. For instance,  the method in question becomes like this

```
public IEnumerable<int> sub_values()
{
    return Traverse().Select(node => node.value);
}
```