# Ordering a self-referencing hierarchy in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class called `NavigationElement` that looks like this

```
public class NavigationElement
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Link { get; set; }
  public int SortOrder { get; set; }
  public bool Visible { get; set; }
  public int? ParentId { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<NavigationElement> Children { get; set; }
  public virtual NavigationElement Parent { get; set; }

  public NavigationElement()
  {
    Children = new List<NavigationElement>();
  }
}
```

As you can see, the class is self referencing. From that, I am creating a site navigation menu with drop downs (hierarchy in play).

I am struggling in the ordering of the items. I want the top-level items to be ordered by the `SortOrder` property, but **everything underneath**, I would like ordered **alphabetically** by the `Title` property.

Here is why I have done so far.

```
var orderedModel = unorderedModel.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder).ThenBy(x => x.Children.OrderBy(y => y.Title).ThenBy(z => z.Children.OrderBy(a => a.Title))).ToList();
```

`unorderedModel` is of type `List<NavigationElementModel>`.

This is compiling, but I get an error when I run the code. The error says:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

Comment: What is `unorderedModel` - list of root elements or flat list with all elements?

Comment: Updated the Q. That is `List<NavigationElementModel>`

Comment: You can't use orderby if your class `NavigationElement` doesn't impletemnt IComparable since, well, it can't compare, thus it can't order

Comment: That was kind of obvious. The question was if it contains **all** elements or only **root** elements?

Comment: It would contain all, but they'll be in a hierarchy. for example `Service` > `Cleaning` > `Bin Cleaning`. For its `ParentId`, `Cleaning` will have the `Id` of `Service`

Comment: Changing SortOrder of child nodes isn't available, is it?

Comment: @SurfinBird no, `SortOrder` is left as 0 for anything that isn't Top Level. That is why I want those sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just go recursive through all children elements and sort it.

Somehting like:

```
var ordered = unorderedModel.OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder).ToList();
ordered.ForEach(OrderChildren);

public void OrderChildren(NavigationElement el)
{
    el.Children = el.Children.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
    if (el.Children != null)
    {
        foreach (var c in el.Children)
        {
            OrderChildren(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
public static class LinqExtension {
   public static IEnumerable<T> SelectManyRecursive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector) {
       if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

       foreach (var i in source) {
           yield return i;

           var children = childrenSelector(i);
           if (children == null) continue;

           foreach (var child in SelectManyRecursive(children, childrenSelector)) {
               yield return child;
           }
       }
   }
}

var orderedModel = unorderedModel
        .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
        .SelectMany(x => new[] { x }.Union(
                x.Children.SelectManyRecursive(y => y.Children)
                        .OrderBy(y => y.Parent.Title) // considering hierarchy
                        .ThenBy(y => y.Title)
                ))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will utilize the approach from [Sort hierarchy with path and depth fields using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921348/sort-hierarchy-with-path-and-depth-fields-using-linq/35923737#35923737) for your case.

First, the general tree traversal helper from my answer to [How to flatten tree via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq/31881243#31881243):

```
public static partial class TreeUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Expand<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> elementSelector)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<T>>();
        var e = source.GetEnumerator();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    var item = e.Current;
                    yield return item;
                    var elements = elementSelector(item);
                    if (elements == null) continue;
                    stack.Push(e);
                    e = elements.GetEnumerator();
                }
                if (stack.Count == 0) break;
                e.Dispose();
                e = stack.Pop();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            e.Dispose();
            while (stack.Count != 0) stack.Pop().Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And the solution of your particular problem:

```
var orderedModel = unorderedModel.Where(item => item.Parent == null).OrderBy(item => item.SortOrder)
    .Expand(item => item.Children != null && item.Children.Any() ? item.Children.OrderBy(child => child.Title) : null)
    .ToList();
```