# Return a List recursively from a tree without instantiating a new list each time in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, recursion

I've created a method in a Quadtree that returns a List of rectangles  where the rectangle structures represent the quadrants. The problem is as you can see below I need to instantiate a new List in each call and I want to avoid it if possible as I think it has great impact in the performance when its's called each 1/30 to 1/60 seconds (a game loop)

```
public List<Rectangle> GetQuads()
{
    List<Rectangle> list = new List<Rectangle> ();

    if(this.HasChilds)
    {
        foreach(QuadTree node in this.Nodes)
        {
            list.AddRange(node.GetQuads ());
        }
    }

    list.Add (this.Bounds);

    return list;
}
```

I'm aware that I can pass a List as parameter and work with that list inside the method but then I'm forced to instantiate the List outside and I want to avoid that too in order to work with the result "on the fly" and do stuff like:

```
foreach(Rectangle quad in QuadTree.GetQuads().OrderByDescending(x=>x.Width))
{
     //DO STUFF
}
```

Is there any way to achieve what I'm asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the recursive code to a private method with additional argument and call it from the public method:

```
public List<Rectangle> GetQuads()
{
    var list = new List<Rectangle> ();
    AddQuads(list);
    return list;
}

private void AddQuads(List<Rectangle> list)
{
    if(this.HasChilds)
    {
        foreach(QuadTree node in this.Nodes)
        {
            node.AddQuads(list);
        }
    }
    list.Add(this.Bounds);
}
```

However, if you really want to work "on the fly", you shouldn't use `List` at all, but utilize a tree **iterator**, for instance the one from [How to flatten tree via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq/31881243#31881243). This way you will be able to also select/filter/sort etc. by other properties than `Bounds`.

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to return a `List<T>` and not `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Thank you, I'll implement this approach but instead of declaring the list into the method I'll do it into my class and check null for first instantiate as suggested by @nicomp. By the way, I don't have any real reason to use List so I'll check that link , thanks for the info.

Comment: You are welcome. Please note that class field is bit dangerous to get out of sync if you modify your tree.

Answer (score 1):

declare, but don't instantiate, at a broader scope perhaps at the class level:

```
List<Rectangle> list;
```

then in the GetQuads method do this:

```
if (list == null) {list = new List<Rectangle> ();}
```

Comment: Declaring the list at class level is a good point but this alone isn't enough since I need to clear the list automatically between calls and I can only do that by splitting my method in two as @Ivan Stoev said.