# LINQ List searching multiple lists. Returning a single list

Tags: c#, linq, list, recursion

I am looking to build a function to create a single list or elements.

This list of elements determines solo based on what values are in my dynamic list of lists.

For example
List A hold an object that holds List B. and List B holds an object that holds List C

In List A B or C there is a chance that they are they hold a special value.

I need to make a function that will search every list and return only the values that hold the special value.

I tried looking into recursive functions and I think I am close.

```
public ObservableCollection<ListViewItem> RecursiveActionBuilder(List<IMetaData> pList)
    {
        if (pList == null)
            return null;

        List<ActionObject> actions = new List<ActionObject>();

        for (int x = 0; x < pList.Count; x++)
        {
            ActionObject child = RecursiveActionBuilder(pList[x]);
            if (child == null)
                continue;
            else
                actions.Add(child);
        }

        ObservableCollection<ListViewItem> items = new ObservableCollection<Models.Items.ListViewItem>();

        for (int x = 0; x < actions.Count; x++)
            items.Add(new ListViewItem()
            {
                Values = new ListViewValue[]
                {
                    new ListViewValue() { Value = actions[x].Command },
                    new ListViewValue() { Value = actions[x].Target },
                    new ListViewValue() { Value = actions[x].Value },
                    new ListViewValue() { Value = actions[x].Comment }
                }
            });

        return items;
    }

    public ActionObject RecursiveActionBuilder(IMetaData pObj)
    {
        if (pObj == null)
            return null;

        if (pObj.Children == null)
        {
            if (pObj.Tag == Enums.TestType.Action)
                return pObj as ActionObject;
            else
                return null;
        }


        ActionObject action = new ActionObject();

        for (int x = 0; x < pObj.Children.Count; x++)
        {
            ActionObject child = RecursiveActionBuilder(pObj.Children[x]);
            if (child == null)
                continue;
            else return child;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However it isn't grabbing all the 'actions' its only grabbing one, then jumping out.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem apparently is because this method

```
public ActionObject RecursiveActionBuilder(IMetaData pObj)
```

is returning single object, instead of multiple objects as the question implies.

It can be fixed, but I will suggest you a slightly different approach.

Following the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, what you really need in such scenarios is a LINQ like method which flattens tree structure like your `IMetaData` (which according to your code contains `List<IMetaData> Children` property/field). For instance, you can use the custom extension method from my answer to [How to flatten tree via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq/31881243#31881243):

```
public static class TreeHelpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Expand<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> elementSelector)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<T>>();
        var e = source.GetEnumerator();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    var item = e.Current;
                    yield return item;
                    var elements = elementSelector(item);
                    if (elements == null) continue;
                    stack.Push(e);
                    e = elements.GetEnumerator();
                }
                if (stack.Count == 0) break;
                e.Dispose();
                e = stack.Pop();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            e.Dispose();
            while (stack.Count != 0) stack.Pop().Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can utilize the full power of LINQ for solving your concrete problem:

```
public ObservableCollection<ListViewItem> RecursiveActionBuilder(List<IMetaData> pList)
{
    if (pList == null)
        return null;

    var items = pList
        .Expand(e => e.Children)
        .Select(e => e.Children == null && e.Tag == Enums.TestType.Action ? e as ActionObject : null)
        .Where(e => e != null)
        .Select(e => new ListViewItem()
        {
            Values = new ListViewValue[]
            {
                new ListViewValue() { Value = e.Command },
                new ListViewValue() { Value = e.Target },
                new ListViewValue() { Value = e.Value },
                new ListViewValue() { Value = e.Comment }
            }
        });

    return new ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>(items);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, Sorry I am just getting back to you now. Give me a couple hours and I can review your answer asap!

Comment: No problem mate, I'm not on hurry :)

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you Ivan!