# How to draw dynamic rectangles hierarchical? (MVVM-WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm

The Title explains my question I guess. I have one root rectangle which has children rectangles which can also have children rectangles. What would be the best way to draw all of them dynamically on a canvas?

My Rectangle-ViewModel:

```
    public class SketchRectangleViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {

        public SketchRectangleViewModel(SketchRectangle sr)
        {
            _id = sr.Id;
            _x = sr.x;
            _y = sr.y;
            _height = sr.Height;
            _width = sr.Width;
            _name = sr.Name;
            _parentId = sr.ParentId;
        }

        private Guid _id;
        private int _x;
        private int _y;
        private int _height;
        private int _width;
        private Guid _parentId;
        private string _name;
        private ObservableCollection<SketchRectangleViewModel> _children = new ObservableCollection<SketchRectangleViewModel>();
        private bool _isSelected;
    }
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? This is a legit question.

Comment: Don't worry about down-votes, it happens. try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/2745294

Comment: Are the X and Y values of each rectangle coordinates of the parent Canvas or coordinates of the parent rectangle?

Comment: @mm8 coordinates of the parent Canvas since I want to be able to move it around.

Comment: @SushilMate Tried that solution in the beginning but your provided solution doesn't add the childrens to the canvas

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data?

Comment: for a rectangle with children?

Comment: You need to flatten your list of rectangles. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a flat collection of all `SketchRectangleViewModel` objects in your view model:

[How to flatten tree via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq)

...and bind the collection of all `SketchRectangleViewModel` objects to an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="Green" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that you can only bind to *public properties* of the `SketchRectangleViewModel` class, so you need to turn your fields into properties:

```
public double X { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry I had other things to do first and was not at the Computer. Tried it and it works like a charm, thank you! Added the call to flatten my Collection whenever the Rectangles Collection gets changed or when a new Element is added.