# Recursively iterating through object's properties throws StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, recursion, reflection

I'm recursively iterating through an object's properties using the following method:

```
void GetProps(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return;

    var objType = obj.GetType();
    var properties = objType.GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(obj, null);

        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
        {
            var enumerable = (IEnumerable)value;

            foreach (object child in enumerable)
                GetProps(child);
        }
        else
        {
            GetProps(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The object is very complex (over 30 classes). I'm getting a `StackOverflowException` when going deeper into the object at `GetProps(value`.

Is there a way to catch the exception and check why it's failing, and, solve the problem?

**EDIT**

I added a fail-safe at the top of the method:

```
if (visited.Contains(obj))
    return;

visited.Add(obj);
```

The problem is not with circular references (which I don't have) but with property types such as `DateTime`, `int` and `decimal`. which was assuming they're primitive but the `IsPrimitive` property is `false`.

Can I differentiate between such types and my own classes?

Comment: You should look up the Visitor pattern and only traverse object types that have not been visited.

Comment: Add an exception handlers try/catch.  Error is probably you are running out of memory.  Open Task manager while code is running.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry but that is wrong on both accounts. First, as @Daniel indicates in his answer, you can not catch a `StackOverlflowException` that you did not maunally throw. Second, if the issue was that the process is running out of memory, then an `OutOfMemoryException` would be thrown, now a stack overflow.

Comment: You likely don't even need recursion here.  See Eric Lippert's approach to traversing via stack:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20335369/1316856

Comment: Wouldn't a `string` also pass your `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom` condition?

Comment: Is your intention to traverse the transitive closure of all the *types* of the properties, or all the *values* of the properties?  Because there is no guarantee that either is finite, but there are ways to make the former terminate. There are some subtleties here. For example, consider `class C<T> { public C<C<T>> CCT => new C<C<T>>(); }`  If you have a `C<int>` in hand then the value of `c.CCT` is a `C<C<int>>`, and the value of *its* CCT is a `C<C<C<int>>>` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example not using recursion, which leverages Eric Lippert's [explicit stack approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20335369/1316856).  I don't know if the behavior with strings is as you intended, but this may prevent your stack from blowing:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetPropertiesDepthFirst(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        yield break;

    var stack = new Stack<object>();
    stack.Push(obj);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        yield return current;

        var objType = current.GetType();
        var properties = objType.GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(current, null);
            if (value == null)
                continue;

            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                var enumerable = (IEnumerable)value;
                foreach (object child in enumerable)
                    stack.Push(child);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also for IEnumerables with defined indexes, you may want to exclude Indexed Properties:

```
objType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

[A `StackOverflowException` can't be caught](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2008/10/22/when-can-you-catch-a-stackoverflowexception/) unless you threw it, because it indicates a fatal problem with your application.

Most likely this happens because you have a circular reference. I.e. an object that contains another object which contains a reference to the original object. There may be an arbitrary number of hierarchy levels between the two classes.

You need to implement some kind of mechanism to stop traversing an object that you already traversed, e.g. with the help of a hash set.

Comment: I don't have circular references although I have classes used in different parts of the graph (though not same instances).

Comment: A stackoverflow exception usually happens only after hundreds of nested function calls. So I am pretty sure that you have a circular reference :-)

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono - You don't need necessarily circular object references, this could also happen with a value type with a property returning the declaring type e.g. `DateTime`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - For example `DateTime` contains a `Today` property which returns a `DateTime` which contains a `Today` property...