# Performance of reverse-mapping collection

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a collection of objects where every object has a unique string Id, and any other object can contain entirely arbitrary (many-to-one) "Links" to another object.  I also want to be able to generate a "usage map" which is the reverse index -- given any one object, which other objects are linked either directly to it or to a child of it?  (Here a "child" is defined as any object with a matching prefix Id, as the Id is a dotted-path notation.)

So `Baz.Boz` might be one object that links to `Foo.Bar` -- the usage map should then reflect that both `Foo` and `Foo.Bar` (but not `Foo.Bob`) are used by `Baz.Boz`.

This is the code used to calculate the usage map:

```
// builds Id => links that link to Id or one of Id's children (by prefix)
public IDictionary<string, IList<Link>> CalculateUsageMap()
{
    var all = All();
    var links = all.Values
        .SelectMany(o => o.Links ?? Enumerable.Empty<Link>())
        .ToList();
    return all.Keys.ToDictionary(i => i, i => links.Where(k => IsLinkedTo(k, i)).ToList());
    // this last line is very slow
}

private static bool IsLinkedTo(Link link, string candidateId)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(link.TargetId)
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(candidateId)
        && link.TargetId.StartsWith(candidateId, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

This is the supporting structure behind it:

```
public interface ILinkable
{
    string Id { get; }
    IEnumerable<ILinkable> Children { get; }
    IEnumerable<Link> Links { get; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public ILinkable Source { get; } // our immediate owner
    public string TargetId { get; }
    // plus constructors etc that's irrelevant at present
}

public ILinkable Root { get; }

public IDictionary<string, ILinkable> All()
{
    var tree = new Dictionary<string, ILinkable>();
    AddWithDescendants(tree, Root);
    return tree;
}

private static void AddWithDescendants(IDictionary<string, ILinkable> tree, ILinkable obj)
{
    tree.Add(obj.Id, obj);

    foreach (var child in obj.Children ?? Enumerable.Empty<ILinkable>())
    {
        AddWithDescendants(tree, child);
    }
}
```

This works, but in a tree with ~14k objects and ~3k links (producing ~20k usages) this takes ~5s to generate, which is longer than I'd like.  (I've checked and `All()` and calculating `links` takes basically no time; it's all being spent inside `ToDictionary`.)

**Is there some way to improve performance of this line?**  My first thought was using something like `GroupJoin`, but since we're "joining" on prefix-equality rather than actual equality that doesn't really work.  I would prefer to keep this in pure code, not involving a database.

(I did attempt to write a custom equality comparer for `GroupJoin` but this ended up being both slower and producing the wrong results, with only ~7k of usage output.  And it's dubious anyway since this is an asymmetric match, while equality comparers assume symmetry.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but an alternate way to express the relationship is that a link with target `a.b.c.d` represents a usage of `a`, `a.b`, `a.b.c` and `a.b.c.d`.  Or conversely that if `a.b.c.d` is the target of a link then both itself and all of its parents are usages of that link.  (But currently the object model doesn't have an easy way for child to navigate to parent, other than by looking up its id prefix.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of this code

```
return all.Keys.ToDictionary(i => i, i => links.Where(k => IsLinkedTo(k, i)).ToList());
```

is quadratic `O(N*M)`, where `N` is `all.Keys.Count` and `M` is `links.Count`. So not surprisingly it is slow.

Since what you are trying to achieve is essentially finding all `ILinkable.Id` being *prefix* of `Link.TargetId`, you need an efficient data structure optimized for such operation. Such data structure exists and is called [Prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Following is a quick implementation for your case:

```
class ItemMap : IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string, IReadOnlyList<Link>>>
{
    class Node
    {
        public Node(char key) => Key = key;
        public char Key { get; }
        public NodeMap Children;
        public ILinkable Item;
        public List<Link> Links;
        public IReadOnlyList<Link> ItemLinks => Links ?? (Item != null ? NoLinks : null);
        public static IReadOnlyList<Link> NoLinks => Array.Empty<Link>(); 
    }

    struct NodeMap
    {
        Dictionary<char, Node> items;
        public IEnumerable<Node> Items => items?.Values;
        public bool TryGetItem(char key, out Node item, bool create = false)
        {
            item = null;
            if ((items == null || !items.TryGetValue(key, out item)) && create)
                (items ?? (items = new Dictionary<char, Node>())).Add(key, item = new Node(key));
            return item != null;
        }
    }

    NodeMap RootNodes;

    IEnumerable<Node> Nodes
        => RootNodes.Items?.Expand(e => e.Children.Items) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Node>();

    IEnumerable<Node> ItemNodes
        => Nodes.Where(n => n.Item != null);

    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IReadOnlyList<Link>>> Items
        => ItemNodes.Select(n => new KeyValuePair<string, IReadOnlyList<Link>>(n.Item.Id, n.ItemLinks));

    public ItemMap(ILinkable tree)
    {
        if (tree == null) return;
        var items = new[] { tree }.Expand(e => e.Children);
        foreach (var item in items)
            AddItem(item);
        var links = Nodes.Where(n => n.Item?.Links != null).SelectMany(n => n.Item.Links);
        foreach (var link in links)
            AddLink(link);
    }

    void AddItem(ILinkable item)
    {
        var node = GetNode(item.Id, create: true);
        if (node == null) return;
        if (node.Item != null) throw new Exception($"Duplicate key: {item.Id}");
        node.Item = item;
        Count++;
    }

    void AddLink(Link link)
    {
        var key = link.TargetId;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) return;
        ref var nodes = ref RootNodes;
        for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!nodes.TryGetItem(key[i], out var node)) break;
            // Add to each item in the prefix path
            if (node.Item != null && node.Item != link.Source)
                (node.Links ?? (node.Links = new List<Link>())).Add(link);
            nodes = ref node.Children;
        }
    }

    Node GetNode(string key, bool create = false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) return null;
        Node node = null;
        ref var nodes = ref RootNodes;
        for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!nodes.TryGetItem(key[i], out node, create)) break;
            nodes = ref node.Children;
        }
        return node;
    }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, IReadOnlyList<Link>>> GetEnumerator() => Items.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

(Note: Instead of recursive tree traversals, in many places I use the generic DRY `Expand` method from my answer to [How to flatten tree via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq/31881243#31881243)))

All the hard work happens in the class constructor. The first pass adds all items to the prefix tree. Then the second pass associates the links with each item. The first operation is `O(N)`, second is `O(M)`, so the overall is `O(M+N)`, i.e. linear and much faster than the original.

Now you can easily build the desired dictionary (I've changed the interfaces to their `ReadOnly` variants):

```
public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<Link>> CalculateUsageMap()
    => new ItemMap(Root).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

But note that this is not even needed, because the prefix tree can be used effectively as dictionary. Implementing the read only dictionary interface is quite easy - change the class declaration to

```
class ItemMap : IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<Link>>
```

and add the following few lines inside

```
public IEnumerable<string> Keys => Items.Select(e => e.Key);

public IEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<Link>> Values => Items.Select(e => e.Value);

public IReadOnlyList<Link> this[string key]
    => TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : throw new KeyNotFoundException();

public bool ContainsKey(string key) => TryGetValue(key, out _);

public bool TryGetValue(string key, out IReadOnlyList<Link> value)
    => (value = GetNode(key)?.ItemLinks) != null;
```

Now you can remove the `ToDictionary` call:

```
public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<Link>> CalculateUsageMap()
    => new ItemMap(Root);
```

---

The above prefix tree implementation use `Dictionary<char, Node>` for child node list storage/traversal. This might use much more memory. Since the whole implementation is encapsulated in `NodeMap`, you can experiment with different data structures and measure the performance and memory usage.

For instance, the following is another implementation which uses `null`, single `Node` or sorted `List<Node>` as storage, and binary search for locating the `Node` by key in the sorted list:

```
struct NodeMap
{
    object items; // null, Node or sorted List<Node>
    public IEnumerable<Node> Items => items is Node node ? new[] { node } : items as IEnumerable<Node>;
    public bool TryGetItem(char key, out Node item, bool create = false)
    {
        item = null;
        if (items == null)
        {
            if (create) items = item = new Node(key);
        }
        else if (items is Node node)
        {
            if (node.Key == key) item = node;
            else if (create) items = node.Key < key ? new List<Node>(2) { node, (item = new Node(key)) } : new List<Node>(2) { (item = new Node(key)), node };
        }
        else
        {
            var nodeList = (List<Node>)items;
            int lo = 0, hi = nodeList.Count - 1;
            while (lo <= hi)
            {
                int mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
                node = nodeList[mid];
                if (node.Key == key) { item = node; break; }
                if (node.Key < key) lo = mid + 1; else hi = mid - 1;
            }
            if (item == null && create) nodeList.Insert(lo, item = new Node(key));
        }
        return item != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this improve performance when the prefix tree is constructed only at the point of constructing the reverse mapping and used only once?  I cannot change the original data structure (that `All()` iterates through -- and it wouldn't be correct to do so anyway, in other contexts the prefix is irrelevant).

Comment: @Miral Of course, as you can see I've used it only to implement `CaclulateUsageMap` on top of your original data structure. As I mentioned, the time complexity of constructing it is O(N+M) vs O(N*M) of the original code. Which means for N=14k and M=3K the above would perform ~17K operations vs ~51M originally, which should be a huge difference. Unfortunately I have no data to test, but can do that with yours and compare.

Comment: Your first version works really well with my dataset (at least for time; I didn't check memory usage).  From 4.60s in the original version to 0.06s with your version, which is definitely noticeable!  Your binary search version has a bug though, and never completes.  I changed it to use `List<T>.BinarySearch` instead and this works but takes 0.10s -- which is still an improvement, but less so.

Comment: Actually no, I take that back.  The first NodeMap and the second-with-patched-BinarySearch versions have equivalent performance within the margin of error of my test.  In which case (while I still haven't checked specifically) I assume the second one is marginally better due to simpler memory usage.

Comment: Also I wasn't aware that C# 7.3 was a thing or that it needed to be enabled explicitly rather than just automatically becoming available, so that's interesting as well.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the second variant quickly and apparently made some annoying bugs, which are now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, here is the version of `NodeMap` from [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62086158/43534) which uses the built-in `List<T>.BinarySearch` instead:

```
struct NodeMap
{
    object items; // null, Node or sorted List<Node>
    private static readonly IComparer<Node> NodeComparer
        = Comparer<char>.Default.SelectComparer((Node n) => n.Key);
    public IEnumerable<Node> Items => items is Node node
        ? new[] { node } : items as IEnumerable<Node>;
    public bool TryGetItem(char key, out Node item, bool create = false)
    {
        item = null;
        if (items == null)
        {
            if (create) items = item = new Node(key);
        }
        else if (items is Node node)
        {
            if (node.Key == key) item = node;
            else if (create) items = node.Key < key
               ? new List<Node>(2) { node, (item = new Node(key)) }
               : new List<Node>(2) { (item = new Node(key)), node };
        }
        else
        {
            var nodeList = (List<Node>)items;
            var newNode = new Node(key);
            var index = nodeList.BinarySearch(newNode, NodeComparer);
            if (index >= 0) item = nodeList[index];
            else if (create) nodeList.Insert(~index, (item = newNode));
        }
        return item != null;
    }
}
```

Note that here I'm using a helper class to generate an `IComparer<Node>` from a lambda; equivalently you can make `Node` implement `IComparable<T>` (although that might be very slightly slower, apparently?).

Also interesting is that I also tried an alternative version which always created the `List<Node>` instead of supporting leaf Nodes (eliminating the middle branch), but that doubled the time from ~0.10s to ~0.20s.  Which would still be good enough, but might as well go with the fastest option.

---

One more variation: since my ids are dotted-path segments that are atomic (ie. I only care about path-segment prefixes, not path-substring prefixes), I tried using string keys split at the segment level instead; replacing `NodeMap` like so:

```
struct NodeMap
{
    object items; // null, Node or sorted List<Node>
    private static readonly IComparer<Node> NodeComparer
        = StringComparer.Ordinal.SelectComparer((Node n) => n.Key);
    public IEnumerable<Node> Items => items is Node node
        ? new[] { node } : items as IEnumerable<Node>;
    public bool TryGetItem(string key, out Node item, bool create = false)
    {
        item = null;
        if (items == null)
        {
            if (create) items = item = new Node(key);
        }
        else if (items is Node node)
        {
            if (node.Key == key) item = node;
            else if (create) items = StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(node.Key, key) < 0
                ? new List<Node>(2) { node, (item = new Node(key)) }
                : new List<Node>(2) { (item = new Node(key)), node };
        }
        else
        {
            var nodeList = (List<Node>)items;
            var newNode = new Node(key);
            var index = nodeList.BinarySearch(newNode, NodeComparer);
            if (index >= 0) item = nodeList[index];
            else if (create) nodeList.Insert(~index, (item = newNode));
        }
        return item != null;
    }
}
```

And then in `AddLink`/`GetNode` changed the key loop to:

```
foreach (var segment in key.Split('.'))
```

This has now improved performance again (back to ~0.05s, similar to Ivan's original dictionary-based version).  And while I haven't verified all the entries, it's producing the same number of results as the "known good" version so it should still be correct.