# Flattening a list of lists, using LINQ, to get a list of parent/child

Tags: c#, list, linq, flatten

I am trying to flatten a parent/child list, of the same `<Person>` type. The difficulty here, is that I would
like to merge both the parents and children into a flat `<Person>` list.

Closest I got was:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}

List<Person> parents = new List<Person>() {
    new Person() {
        Name = "parentA",
        Children = new List<Person>() {
            new Person() { Name = "childB" },
            new Person() { Name = "childC" }
        }
    },
    new Person() {
        Name = "parentD",
        Children = new List<Person>() {
            new Person() { Name = "childE" },
            new Person() { Name = "childF" }
        }
    }
};

var result = parents.SelectMany(parent => parent.Children
    .Select(child => parent.Name + ", " + child.Name));
```

Which gives me the result:

```
parentA, childB
parentA, childC
parentD, childE
parentD, childF
```

What I'm looking for is to get a `<Person>` list such as:

```
parentA
childB
childC
parentD
childE
childF
```

Keeping the order, or the performance is not important. But I would like, *if possible*, to stick to pure LINQ and LINQ methods.

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq

Comment: `SelectMany(parent => parent.Children.Append(parent).Select(x => x.Name))` if you only need to go one level deep?

Comment: If you want to preserve the order that the parent is first, then children, as in your question, you could use `Prepend` instead of `Append`.  `parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children.Prepend(p));`

Comment: You guys got it, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!
Can I mark a comment as the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments on my initial post, I was able to get what I was looking for.

The solution only works on one level, which is what I needed. It could be made recursive to go deeper though:

```
var result = parents.SelectMany(person => person.Children
        .Prepend(person))
    .Select(p => p.Name);
```

Gave me the expected result:

```
parentA 
childB 
childC 
parentD 
childE 
childF
```

Which then allowed me to use all the objects in the flattened lists, including the parent objects.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `Concat` in combination with `SelectMany` if you want just *one level deep*:

```
 var parents = ...

 var result = parents
   .SelectMany(person => new Person[] {person}.Concat(person.Children))
   .Select(person => person.Name); // if we want just names

 // Let's have a look
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Comment: Dmitry, your answer was very helpful as well, because somewhere in the code, .Prepend() would come out as not being a method on an ObservableCollection<> for some reason (still haven't figured that one out yet). This worked flawlessly, however. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
parents.ForEach(p => {
        persons.Add(p); 
        persons.AddRange(p.Children);
    }
);


foreach(var person in persons)
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
    }
```

I understand that this isnt a single line but this I suppose is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try following class :

```
    class Person
    {
        public static DataTable dt { get;set;}

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Person> Children { get; set; }

        public void GetTree(Person root)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Parent Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Child Name", typeof(string));
            GetTreeRecursive(root, "");

        }
        public void GetTreeRecursive(Person person, string parentName)
        {
            foreach(Person child in person.Children)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(parentName, child.Name);
                if (child.Children != null)
                {
                    GetTreeRecursive(child, child.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```