# Make EnumerateDirectory stop looking for subfolders if condition is met

Tags: c#, performance, directory

I'm trying to find some directories on a network drive.

I use Directory.EnumerateDirectories for this.
The problem is that it takes very long because there are many subdirectories.

Is there a way to make the function stop searching further down into subdirectories if a match was found and carry on with the next directory on same level?

```
static readonly Regex RegexValidDir = new ("[0-9]{4,}\\.[0-9]+$");
var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(startDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(x => RegexValidDir.IsMatch(x));
```

The directory structure looks like that

```
a\b\20220902.1\c\d\
a\b\20220902.2\c\d\e
a\b\x\20220902.3\
a\b\x\20221004.1\c\
a\b\x\20221004.2\c\
a\b\x\20221004.3\d\e\f\
...
a\v\w\x\20221104.1\c\d
a\v\w\x\20221105.1\c\d
a\v\w\x\20221106.1\c\d
a\v\w\x\20221106.2\c\d
a\v\w\x\20221106.3\c\d
a\v\w\x\20221106.4\
```

I'm interested in the directories with a date in the name only and want to stop searchin further down into the subdirectories of a matching dir.

Another thing is I don't know if the search pattern I'm supplying (*.*) is correct for my usage szenario.

The directories are found relatively quickly, but it then takes another 11 minutes to complete the search function

Comment: "The directories are found relatively quickly, but it then takes another 2-3 minutes to complete the search function" What does that mean? How do you measure case 1 and how case 2 ?

Comment: The for loop I iterate "dirs" is enteres in a few seconds, I can see that my console.writeline of each dir is written quick. after the console.writeline loop I do an OrderBy("DateTime") and this takes 12 ! Minutes to get done.   (Measured with stopwatch)

Comment: The list contains only 23 "top" directories with "date-Directories). The one with most date-dirs has 103 entries. All in all about 500 relevant directories where found. 

I'm using a UNC network share as start directory in a professional GBit network environment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to prune the enumeration efficiently with the built-in [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories) method, in [`SearchOption.AllDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption) mode. My suggestion is to write a custom recursive iterator, that allows to select the children of each individual item:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> children = childrenSelector(item);
        yield return item;
        if (children is null) continue;

        foreach (T child in Traverse(children, childrenSelector))
            yield return child;
    }
}
```

Then for the directories that match the date pattern, you can just return `null` children, effectively stopping the recursion for those directories:

```
IEnumerable<string> query = Traverse(new[] { startDir }, path =>
{
    if (RegexValidDir.IsMatch(path)) return null; // Stop recursion
    return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path);
}).Where(path => RegexValidDir.IsMatch(path));
```

This query is slightly inefficient because the `RegexValidDir` pattern is matched twice for each path (one in the `childrenSelector` and one in the `predicate` of the `Where`). In case you want to optimize it, you could modify the `Traverse` method by replacing the `childrenSelector` with a more complex lambda, that returns both the children and whether the item should be yielded by the iterator: `Func<T, (IEnumerable<T>, bool)> lambda`. Or alternatively use the `Traverse` as is, with the `T` being `(string, bool)` instead of `string`.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll try to follow your aproach and give feedback soon.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Works very well. It takes only about 12 seconds to complete!!
I had to add some exlude direectories but all in all your solution works great.

Comment: @BenHero in case you are interested for a non-recursive variant of the `Traverse`, there are some implementations here: [How to flatten tree via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq) For understanding the theory behind the transformation, this question is quite helpful: [Way to go from recursion to iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration).